# window.resize not working as reloading the resized window

Tags: jquery

Here is my piece of jquery which loading a href link as my window resized to less than 767, this is working fine, it disappear what i want to hide and show what i want to see, but as a click on reload button of browser it puts back the webpage same as it should not be on the window width of below 767.

not working as i refresh the resized web page.

```
$(window).bind('resize', function(e){

    width = $(window).width();

    if (width < 767){
        $("a.collapseListBt").show();
        // do something here
        if ($('.content-box-right').hasClass('show')){
            $('.content-box-right').removeClass('show');
        } 
    } else{
        $("a.collapseListBt").hide();
        $('.content-box-right').addClass('show');
    }

});
```

please suggest how to keep it still and not let move the setting fixed for window width of 767

Comment: ya i know i can, but, can it not be done with jquery?

Comment: put it in a function and call it onload too.

Comment: @shiva agrawal - it could be done with jQuery, but javascript takes much more resources than using css, which some people might interpret as a bad practice when a pure css solution is available

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your javascript

```
$(document).load(function(e){

    width = $(window).width();

    if (width < 767){
        $("a.collapseListBt").show();
        // do something here
        if ($('.content-box-right').hasClass('show')){
            $('.content-box-right').removeClass('show');
        } 
    } else{
        $("a.collapseListBt").hide();
        $('.content-box-right').addClass('show');
    }

});
```

Your problem is that your function is only called on `window.resize`, therefore when you load the page there is nothing to do the job you want it to. More over you really could just use css and media queries for that, in my opinion it would be far better.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the two events together like this:

```
$(window).on('resize load', function(e){

    width = $(window).width();

    if (width < 767){
        $("a.collapseListBt").show();
        // do something here
        if ($('.content-box-right').hasClass('show')){
            $('.content-box-right').removeClass('show');
        } 
     } else{
       $("a.collapseListBt").hide();
        $('.content-box-right').addClass('show');
    }

});
```